# Highcharts dynamically restrict dragging limits

Tags: highcharts, drag

I'd like to dynamically restrict dragging limits (different limits for each point). I tried this (ending with error):

```
chart.series[1].update({dragMinY: 80});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/petiska/6g9tqrh5/2/

```js
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        zoomType: 'xy',
        animation: false,
        type: 'line',
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Highcharts draggable points demo'
    },
    xAxis: [{
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
    },{linkedTo:0, offset:-128.5, lineWidth: 1, tickInterval: 10, zIndex:4}],
    yAxis: [{},{linkedTo:0,tickInterval:9.1}],
    plotOptions: {     
        series: {
            dataLabels:{useHTML: true},
            point: {
                events: {
                    drag: function (e) {
                        $('#drag').html('Dragging <b>' + this.series.name + '</b>, <b>' + this.category + '</b> to <b>' + Highcharts.numberFormat(e.y, 2) + '</b>');
                        //console.log(e);
                        //console.log(e.target)
                        //console.log(e.dragStart.x);
                        var point_index=e.target.index;
                        var point_oldX=e.dragStart.x;
                        var point_oldY=e.dragStart.y;
                        var point_newX=e.x;
                        var point_newY=e.y;
                        chart.series[1].update({dragMinY: 80});
                    },
                    drop: function () {
                        $('#drop').html('In <b>' + this.series.name + '</b>, <b>' + this.category + '</b> was set to <b>' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2) + '</b>');
                        console.log("drop!")
                    }
                }
            },
            stickyTracking: false
        },
        line: {
            cursor: 'ns-resize'
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        yDecimals: 2
    },
    series: [
        {
            type: "treemap",
            layoutAlgorithm: 'stripes',
            alternateStartingDirection: true,
            //  allowDrillToNode: true,
            data: [{id: "NS",name: 'NS_area', value:5},
                   {id: "NS_ABCDE",name: 'NS_ABCDE',value: 6,parent: 'NS'},
                   {id: "NSA",name: 'NSA',value: 1,parent: 'NS_ABCDE'},
                   {id: "A5",name: 'A5',value: 1,parent: 'NSA'},
                   {id: "A4",name: 'A4',value: 1,parent: 'NSA'},
                   {id: "A3",name: 'A3',value: 1,parent: 'NSA'},
                   {id: "A2",name: 'A2',value: 1,parent: 'NSA'},
                   {id: "A1",name: 'A1',value: 1,parent: 'NSA'},
                   {id: "A0",name: 'A0',value: 1,parent: 'NSA'},
                   {id: "NSB",name: 'NSB',value: 1,parent: 'NS_ABCDE'},
                   {id: "B5",name: 'B5',value: 1,parent: 'NSB'},
                   {id: "B4",name: 'B4',value: 1,parent: 'NSB'},
                   {id: "B3",name: 'B3',value: 1,parent: 'NSB'},
                   {id: "B2",name: 'B2',value: 1,parent: 'NSB'},
                   {id: "B1",name: 'B1',value: 1,parent: 'NSB'},
                   {id: "B0",name: 'B0',value: 1,parent: 'NSB'},
                   {id: "NSC",name: 'NSC',value: 1,parent: 'NS_ABCDE'},
                   {id: "C5",name: 'C5',value: 1,parent: 'NSC'},
                   {id: "C4",name: 'C4',value: 1,parent: 'NSC'},
                   {id: "C3",name: 'C3',value: 1,parent: 'NSC'},
                   {id: "C2",name: 'C2',value: 1,parent: 'NSC'},
                   {id: "C1",name: 'C1',value: 1,parent: 'NSC'},
                   {id: "C0",name: 'C0',value: 1,parent: 'NSC'},
                   {id: "NSD",name: 'NSD',value: 1,parent: 'NS_ABCDE'},
                   {id: "D5",name: 'D5',value: 1,parent: 'NSD'},
                   {id: "D4",name: 'D4',value: 1,parent: 'NSD'},
                   {id: "D3",name: 'D3',value: 1,parent: 'NSD'},
                   {id: "D2",name: 'D2',value: 1,parent: 'NSD'},
                   {id: "D1",name: 'D1',value: 1,parent: 'NSD'},
                   {id: "D0",name: 'D0',value: 1,parent: 'NSD'},
                   {id: "NSE",name: 'NSE',value: 1,parent: 'NS_ABCDE'},
                   {id: "E5",name: 'E5',value: 1,parent: 'NSE'},
                   {id: "E4",name: 'E4',value: 1,parent: 'NSE'},
                   {id: "E3",name: 'E3',value: 1,parent: 'NSE'},
                   {id: "E2",name: 'E2',value: 1,parent: 'NSE'},
                   {id: "E1",name: 'E1',value: 1,parent: 'NSE'},
                   {id: "E0",name: 'E0',value: 1,parent: 'NSE'},
                   {id: "NS_NP1",name:" ",value: 1,parent: 'NS',color: "#FFFFFF"},  //this is only to display division lines, any id can be used - not accessed
                   {id: "NS_NP11",name: " ",value: 1,parent: 'NS_NP1'},
                   {id: "NS_NP11",name: " ",value: 1,parent: 'NS_NP1'},
                   {id: "NS_NP11",name: " ",value: 1,parent: 'NS_NP1'},
                   {id: "NS_NP11",name: " ",value: 1,parent: 'NS_NP1'},
                   {id: "NS_NP11",name: " ",value: 1,parent: 'NS_NP1'},
                   {id: "NS_NP2",name:" ",value: 1,parent: 'NS',color: "#FFFFFF"},
                   {id: "NS_NP11",name: " ",value: 1,parent: 'NS_NP2'},
                   {id: "NS_NP11",name: " ",value: 1,parent: 'NS_NP2'},
                   {id: "NS_NP11",name: " ",value: 1,parent: 'NS_NP2'},
                   {id: "NS_NP11",name: " ",value: 1,parent: 'NS_NP2'},
                   {id: "NS_NP11",name: " ",value: 1,parent: 'NS_NP2'},
                   {id: "NS_NP3",name:" ",value: 1,parent: 'NS',color: "#FFFFFF"},
                   {id: "NS_NP4",name:" ",value: 1,parent: 'NS',color: "#FFFFFF"},
                   {id: "NS_NP5",name:" ",value: 1,parent: 'NS',color: "#FFFFFF"},                
                   //{id: "NS_NP",name:" ",value: 5,parent: 'NS',color: "#FFFFFF"},
                   {id: "LT",name: 'LT',value:3},
                   {id: "LT_FGH",value: 7,parent: 'LT'},
                   {id: "LT_FGH_R",parent: 'LT_FGH'},       //force to divide horizontaly or vertically, R-reverse
                   {id: "F",value: 6,parent: 'LT_FGH_R'},
                   {id: "LT_GH",value: 1,parent: 'LT_FGH_R'},
                   {id: "G",value: 2,parent: 'LT_GH'},
                   {id: "H",value: 1,parent: 'LT_GH'},   
                   {id: "LT_NP",name:" ",value: 2,parent: 'LT',color: "#FFFFFF"},
                   {id: "LT_NP1",name:" ",value: 1,parent: 'LT_NP'},    //this is only to display division lines
                   {id: "LT_NP2",name:" ",value: 1,parent: 'LT_NP'},    //this is only to display division lines
                   {id: "LT_NP3",name:" ",value: 1,parent: 'LT_NP'},    //this is only to display division lines
                   {id: "LT_IJK",value: 2,parent: 'LT'},
                   {id: "LT_I",value: 1,parent: 'LT_IJK'},
                   {id: "I0",value: 2,parent: 'LT_I'},
                   {id: "I1",value: 2,parent: 'LT_I'},
                   {id: "LT_J",value: 1,parent: 'LT_IJK'},
                   {id: "J0",value: 2,parent: 'LT_J'},
                   {id: "J1",value: 2,parent: 'LT_J'},
                   {id: "LT_K",value: 1,parent: 'LT_IJK'},
                   {id: "K0",value: 2,parent: 'LT_K'},
                   {id: "K1",value: 2,parent: 'LT_K'},            
                   {id: "SL",name: 'SL',value:1},
                   {id: "C",name: 'C',value:1},
                  ]
        },{
            data: [[0, 90.9], [10,81.81], [20,72.72], [30,63.63],[40,63.63],[50,45.45],[70,45.45],[80,36.36],[85,35],[95,33],[100,33]],
            step: 'left',
            type: 'line',
            yAxis: 0,
            xAxis: 0,
            draggableX: true,
            draggableY: true,
            dragMaxY: 90.9,
            dragMinY: 30,

        },
    ]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/highcharts/draggable-points/master/draggable-points.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/treemap.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 600px"></div>
<div id="drag"></div>
<div id="drop"></div>
<button onclick="drawsomething()">Click me</button>
```

Comment: What do you mean by dynamically here? Would it be sufficient to just be able to set `dragMinY` and `dragMaxY` for each individual point, or does it have to happen on the drag event, in relation to something else (like another point)?

Comment: Yes, it needs to be in relation to neighbors points, e.g. Y value should go more, than left point Y and should stay higher than right point Y. Also the X should be always higher than left point and lower than right point.

Answer (score 1):

As an example of handling `dragMinY` and `dragMaxY` more dynamically I've slightly modified `draggable-points.js`, essentially allowing for a `dragMin` and `dragMax` function instead (or rather, it has higher priority than `dragMinY` and `dragMaxY`). The functions `dragMin` and `dragMax` get two parameters, `XorY` specifying the axis and `point`, being the dragged point.

The change is to the following functions signature and functionality:

```
/**
 * Filter by dragMin and dragMax
 */
function filterRange(newY, point, series, XOrY) {
    var options = series.options,
        dragMin = pick(options.dragMin ? options.dragMin(XOrY, point) : undefined, options['dragMin' + XOrY], undefined),
        dragMax = pick(options.dragMax ? options.dragMax(XOrY, point) : undefined, options['dragMax' + XOrY], undefined),
        precision = pick(options['dragPrecision' + XOrY], undefined);

    if (!isNaN(precision)) {
        newY = Math.round(newY / precision) * precision;
    }

    if (newY < dragMin) {
        newY = dragMin;
    } else if (newY > dragMax) {
        newY = dragMax;
    }
    return newY;
}
```

The product can be seen here: [GitRaw](https://rawgit.com/Ondkloss/draggable-points/dynamic-drag/draggable-points.js) [GitHub](https://github.com/Ondkloss/draggable-points/blob/dynamic-drag/draggable-points.js)

Or in [this JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/6g9tqrh5/59/), where the drag is limited on X between the left and right neighbor, and Y lower than left and higher than right neighbor, as in the below example code:

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
    },
    series: [{
        data: [[0, 90.9], [10,81.81], [20,72.72], [30,63.63],[40,63.63],[50,45.45],[70,45.45],[80,36.36],[85,35],[95,33],[100,33]],
        step: 'left',
        type: 'line',
        draggableX: true,
        draggableY: true,
        dragMin: function(XorY, point) {
            leftPoint = point.series.data[point.index-1];
            rightPoint = point.series.data[point.index+1];
            if('X' == XorY) {
                // Strictly higher than left point, if any
                if(leftPoint) {
                    return leftPoint.x + 1;
                }
                return undefined;
            }
            else {
                // Lower than right point, if any
                if(rightPoint) {
                    return rightPoint.y;
                }
                return undefined;
            }
        },
        dragMax: function(XorY, point) {
            leftPoint = point.series.data[point.index-1];
            rightPoint = point.series.data[point.index+1];
            if('X' == XorY) {
                // Strictly lower than right point, if any
                if(rightPoint) {
                    return rightPoint.x - 1;
                }
                return undefined;
            }
            else {
                // Higher than left point, if any
                if(leftPoint) {
                    return leftPoint.y;
                }
                return undefined;
            }
        }
    }]
});
```

Note that I've simply edited the code created by Torstein Honsi of Highsoft under the MIT License.

Comment: looks nice, will test it more. Also I need to drag first 8 points only in Y axis, is there an easy way? thanks a lot

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6g9tqrh5/10/ which is basicly `if(point.index < 8) { return point.x }`

Comment: @PetrPerner `plotOptions: { series: { stickyTracking: false } }`

Comment: works great! thanks! last thing, I'd like to be able to move in Y axis by certain step size, e.g. 12.

Comment: @PetrPerner glad it works. From what I understand you want to f.x. only be able to move from say 80 to 85, 90, 95... if you chose a step size of 5..? If so this seems separate from the issue of "dynamically restrict dragging limits", and I think there is no built in feature for it so it would demand some custom code. I suggest separating this new requirement into a new question.